# AVFoundation, cut off edges in the preview layer

Tags: ios

I am developing some iOS app, where I need to do some camera scanning. This is my first experience with AVFoundation, previously I developed camera apps with UIImagePickerController, but AVFoundation seems to be more powerful.

The problem is that it cuts off edges in the preview layer, regardless of that I set preview layer's frame as big as view controller's one.

This is my code:

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *photoCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:photoCaptureDevice error:&error];
    if(videoInput){
        [captureSession addInput:videoInput];
        [captureSession startRunning];
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }   
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
    previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    NSLog(@"%f %f", previewLayer.frame.size.width, previewLayer.frame.size.height);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

Would be very thankful for a help,
Artem

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because the aspect ratio of the video that you're capturing is different to that of the screen. There's not much you can do - it's either letter boxing or non uniform scaling of the image. You *can* throw away some pixels on the short edge, which is probably what UIImagePickerController does.

If you want this behaviour, try setting

```
  previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

Comment: And to mimic the Aspect Fit behavior, use AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect.

Answer (score 9):

Actually the solution was pretty simple, as Rhythmic Fistman mentioned there is a property in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer - videoGravity. So to fit the preview layer in your custom view:

```
previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
// Specifies that the player should preserve the video’s aspect ratio and fill the layer’s bounds.
```

or

```
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize; 
// Specifies that the video should be stretched to fill the layer’s bounds.
```

Comment: and the taken image is same size with preview bounds?