# Borders using AVPlayer in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avplayer

I've been playing around with SwiftUI since a few days and I am currently trying to implement a video player, I am struggling with a size issue.

This is my view code:

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        PlayerView()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

This is what's inside PlayerView()

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
  private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    let url = URL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    player.isMuted = true
    player.play()
    
    playerLayer.player = player
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
  }
}
```

Using this code I obtain this:

[image]

There is this extra border (that we can see in blue) that I want to get rid of and I don't know how to do it.

I've tried to set the playerLayer's videoGravity property to :

- resize: I don't have the border anymore but the video is stretched
- resizeAspectFill: I don't have the border anymore but the video is cut

How can I get rid of those borders while preserving the original ratio and size provided by the video?

Comment: Set background color to white instead?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve the problem, the frame is still bigger than the video itself.

Comment: so make the frame same as the player frame?

Comment: You can only achieve your goal if the view and the video have the same aspect ratio. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868633/22147 for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work this way:

**View Code**

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        PlayerView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .scaledToFill()
     }
}
```

**PlayerUIView.swift**:

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let url = URL(string: "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player.isMuted = true
        player.play()

        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```